# error while installing apache on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: apache2

[image]

I always get the error as seen on the image above. I've tried `apt update` and reinstalling, too. But it does seem to be working when I enter localhost on my browser tho. It just doesn't start when I'm trying to restart the service.

Comment: Instead of posting screenshot, try to paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your image shows there is already a program running that uses port 80.
To find what program is that using port:

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

With the pid you can find the program:

```
ps aux | grep <pid>
```

You need to stop and disable the program before starting apache